# Angular 5 routerLink absolute path with #

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have a url I need to open in a new tab. Unfortionaly, angular generates this url without the #.
We are currently using

```
<!-- HTML -->
<a title="Edit" [routerLink] = "['/object/object2', value]"> {{value}} </a>

// Angular AppModule
RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, { useHash: true, onSameUrlNavigation:'reload' })
```

The url generated http://localhost:4200/object/object2/123456.

The url I need to open it in a new tab  http://localhost:4200/#/object/object2/123456.

I've done a lot of research so this mostly to settle for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are two route solutions in angular, one is based on Hash and the other is based on window.history.

The # is not included because you are using the historyL routing scheme by default. If a hash is required, the official document gives a definition：

[You can go old-school with the HashLocationStrategy by providing the useHash: true in an object as the second argument of the RouterModule.forRoot() in the AppModule](https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // .../#/crisis-center/
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I did this but the url that's generated by routerLink is without the #